# How to calculate perimeter of polygons in Quantum GIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

Is there a way to calculate perimeter of polygons with the field calculator of qgis, like there is for area calculation?[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using `$perimeter`

The feature is there, just not exposed via the UI.

*Note: I'm currently working on a better UI then the current one that will expose all the possible functions. See http://hub.qgis.org/issues/3488*

Comment: Although I posted an answer, I like this one better because you don't need to create a new shapefile just to update or add a new column in the attribute table.

Comment: Btw, where can one find a comprehensive list of all possible but unexposed features like $perimeter?

Comment: Clicking on the Help button in the field calculator should give you a up to date list.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Ftools/Vector Plugin.  `Vector > Geometry Tools > Export/Add Geometry Columns`.  This creates a new shapefile the with `Area` and `Perimeter` columns.

[image]

Comment: Sneaky but Awesoem